# casper-rw persistence on FAT32 partition

Tags: ubuntu, persistence

Is there any way to run Ubuntu from USB stick with a `FAT32` `casper-rw` persistence partition? If I use an `Ext2` `casper-rw` partition everything works fine. However, if I switch to `FAT32`, the system gives the following error during boot:

```
(initramfs) aufs mount failed
```

I guess this happens because `aufs` cannot handle `FAT32`. Is there any way to work around this so that I am able to access the persistence partition from Windows too?

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, one can achieve Gabriel goal (have access to the persistent data from the live as from any host OS) using at least one of these two ways:

### A - Make a Data partition

1. Make your persistent partition just big enough for the *applications* you'll add or update.
2. Then create a third, Fat32 partition for all your upcoming persistent data.
3. Use any tool that makes your third (Data) partition apears first for Windows, so that it let you use it easily. `RMPrepUSB` does this in half a minute, following
   their [tutorial](http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/multipartufd) : point « 4a. Use RMPrepUSB » alone does the job
   well (2).

After what you can use this Data partition to store/read your files from either the live system and any host OS (Android included which is nice :). I also symlink my live system's user $HOME/{Documents,Images,and so on} from the Data partition. This way I don't even have to think about where to put or find them :)

### B - Add read/write support to the Windows host for ext partitions

With either of these tools: `Explorer2fs` (read), `Ext2 IFS` (read/write)  [Accessing a Linux Ext2 or Ext3 partiton from Windows](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/accessing-a-linux-ext2-or-ext3-partiton-from-windows/) or [`Ext2FSd`](http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/) (read/write Ext2/3/4). But this method requires the partition to be the first or you'll get stucked by (1)

(1) Windows is unable to use partition #2+ on a USB removable media.
(2) If you know how to swap the partitions order for Windows under *nix, you might want to share it :)

Answer (score 0):

No, `aufs` handles FAT32 perfectly.

Check out [Slax Linux](http://www.slax.org/)

You must have done something wrong. Need more details to diagnostic. E.g. how did you switch persistence partition from Ext2 to FAT32, in details?